# How to return values across modules with tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have one module of my program, that uses a class in another module to create an object, for a short time. When the object has been destroyed, I need a value to be returned.

Here is the object that is created:

```
class ButtonWindow():
    def __init__(self, master, posx, posy):
        ''' Initialises the TK root window'''

        self.master = master
        master.configure(bg = "light pink")
        master.geometry("20x40+" + str(posx) +"+"+str(posy-20))
        master.option_add("*Font", "Helvetica")


        options = ("Public", "Child", "Over 65", "Staff", "Governor")
        self.bookingType = StringVar()
        self.bookingType.set(options[0])

        seatingMenu = OptionMenu(master, self.bookingType, *options, command=self.updateValue)
        seatingMenu.pack(side=TOP)

    def updateValue(self,value):
        self.master.destroy()
        return self.bookingType.get()
```

As you can see, when the value of the option menu is changed, I need to update the value of a variable in a different module. How can I return the value from this class, and destroy the tk `root` at the same time? Once the `root` is destroyed, the value no longer exists. And once I return a value in `updateValue` it can no longer run the `destroy` function. I need to be able to do both.
Where the object is created:

```
    self.seatMenu = seat_menu.createWindow(self.button.winfo_rootx(), 
    self.button.winfo_rooty(), self.master)

    self.bookingType = #get the value of the option menu from the 
    #self.seatMenu window
```

Comment: Instances of this class don't "own" `master`, so having it destroy it doesn't seem like a good design. It's also unclear what you mean by "return" the value. Tkinter programs are mostly user-event-driven, but it sounds like you're trying to do procedural-style programming with it. Please [edit] your question and add code demonstrating how you intend on using this class.

Comment: master is the Tk root, I don't see any way to get rid of the root without destroy? I have added a short snippet of my other class that creates the object, and shows the wanted outcome. I would like self.bookingType to be the value of self.bookingType.get() from the ButtonWindow object. @martineau

Comment: @Mattattack: **Why** do you call `seat_menu.createWindow(...` instead of `ButtonWindow(...`?

Comment: Haha just noticed how ineffective that is! I have a small procedure at the bottom of the module that simply creates the object. Really not sure why, I will change this now. Thanks @stovfl

Comment: You can call `master.withdraw()` to hide the root window.

Comment: You can access the value via `instanceOfButtonWindow.bookingType.get()`.  According to your provided code, it may be `self.seatMenu.bookingType.get()`.

Comment: You can inherit from `simpledialog.Dialog` which will take care of returning a value and where you override inherited medthods to create the GUI. See [Dialog Windows](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm)

Comment: Thanks @acw1668, but, I need to do this specifically after I have changed the value of the optionmenu, which is why I am trying to use command=(...